# Auto Sizing and Auto Wrappin in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

So I am looking for some way to auto wrap text in my excel document, posisbly based on number of characters per line.

I would also like for my cells to continue auto sizing, I have used the following VBA code for it:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Value In Target.Columns
    Worksheets(Sh.Name).Columns(Value.Column).AutoFit
Next Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to wrap a cell? How do you know which cells to wrap? What's the max. number of characters you want per line? Do you want a wrap or could we insert a manual line break where you'd want the wrap?

Comment: Hi Bruce, all very good points. I was wondering if there was a VBA way (like the auto sizing column code) that would auto wrap any cell that has more than say 150 characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Val As Range
For Each Val In Target.Columns
    Worksheets(Sh.Name).Columns(Val.Column).AutoFit
    If Len(Val) > 150 Then
        Val.WrapText = True
    End If
Next Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note: I suggest not using `Value` as a variable, since it's a "reserved word" in VBA.  I also assume `Value` is a cell, so I defined it as a Range.  It will check if `Value` is over 150 characters, and if so, wrap text.

If that doesn't work, here's a general way to check if a cell has over 150 characters, and if so, wrap text:

```
Sub autoFitCell()
Dim cel As Range
Set cel = Range("A1")
If Len(cel) > 150 Then
    cel.WrapText = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm I realised that 150 may have been to much so I copy/pasted the First VBA code and changed >150 to >30 and then closed the VBA Editor. It does not seemed o have done anything.

When I double click on a Cell it opens VBA and a pop up stating 'Compile Error: Invalid Next Control Variable Reference'